# How to extract specific parameter from different URLs

Tags: javascript

I've looked on similiar topics but no one seems to answer my question.

I've URL that looks like this:

```
https://dummy.com/job/test
```

I need to extract `test` so I am using:

```
 function getIdentificator(){
 let URL = window.location.pathname;
 let Id = URL.slice(URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 return Id;
}
```

It gives me what I want but sometimes the URL is different. For example:

```
 https://dummy.com/job/testwz/something
```

I only need `testwz`.

Or:

```
 https://dummy.com/job/test-ab?somethingmore2132
```

I only need `test-ab`.

Or:

```
 https://dummy.com/job/test
```

I only need `test`.

Or:

```
 https://dummy.com/job/5423
```

I need `5423` from this.

Value I'm interested in always appear after `job/` but in different variations as said before. Key value may be followed by: `nothing`, `/` or `?`.
Is there any way to extract this value in all examples with JavaScript? If not I can use jQuery as well.

Comment: `urlVariable.split('/').pop()`  This question has been asked before.

Comment: @taplar answer is good. Or use a regular expression (regexp). Should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: Or use the URL class, as shown in the duplicate...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think that would only work if the value being sought was actually a querystring parameter. In the examples given you can see it is mostly actually looking for the part of the URL which occurs after the "job" section.

Comment: @ADyson Retracted the close vote. Now, my challenge to you: find the duplicate of this question, since I know there are many.

Comment: krascos, will "job" always be the first part of the URL path following the domain? If so then [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54557286/5947043) is the simple solution. If that is not a consistent thing, then you might need something more complex like a regular expression.

Comment: @Taplar that won't work because in an example like `https://dummy.com/job/testwz/something` as given in the question, the target part of the URL (`testwz`) is not the last item.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your effort. 'Job' will always be a part of the URL path. I'll test it in a few hours and let you guys now if it works.

Comment: " 'Job' will always be a part of the URL path." ...ok thanks but if you read my comment again you'll see that's not what I asked. I asked if it will always be **in the same place** in the URL path (i.e. in the first position after the domain name) - that assumption is crucial to the answer I linked to.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, I was in hurry. "Job" will always be in the same place (after domain name) so the Mike's answer is complex solution to my problem. Once again thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your path will always begin with `/job` no matter the domain:

```
return window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to give you this example:
this is the question's url: 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556911/how-to-extract-specific-parameter-from-different-urls`

if you do `window.location.pathname` you will get :
`"/questions/54556911/how-to-extract-specific-parameter-from-different-urls"`

now, if you do...

`window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

you will get:

`how-to-extract-specific-parameter-from-different-urls`

And I think this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: In the examples given you can see it is actually looking for the part of the URL which occurs after the "job" section...but I don't know if it's guaranteed that it will always be at a specific index. Also your answer would be a lot more helpful if it actually dealt with the scenarios given in the question rather than an invented one.

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()` will be too simplistic in a case given in the question: `https://dummy.com/job/testwz/something` because "testwz" is not the last item. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jx8w6rL0/3/ .

Comment: Again I urge you to use the actual examples from the question - that way you can actually test if your code meets all the different requirements, as well as making the answer much more relevant.